# Blank Graphical Layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[image]

I don't get this. I've searched everywhere and no one's answers have solved this for me.
Why does this keep happening? I can't do anything! The XML Code is still there, but it doesn't show anything in the Graphical Editor. The Palette comes up if I change it to "4in WVGA (Nexus S)" or some other configuration, but I still can't see anything and the Theme drop down menu is unselectable. All my XML documents are like that.

Comment: I dunno man.  The damn thing randomly works and then doesn't for me as well.  Sometimes switching the target platform makes it work better... e.g. Android 3.0 instead of 2.1.  Have you tried updating your android tools and Eclipse to the latest version of everything?

Comment: I know my Eclipse is updated, I just checked. I'm installing some "Archives" in my Android SDK at the moment.

Comment: Eclipse is a dog. Don't you EVER, EVER thing that updates will solve your problems :)). They will fix maybe some, and create many others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just delete any custom device screen configuration you have added . It will solve the issue :)

Comment: Actually, this was what fixed it for me. I made this the correct answer. (Note: Had it fixed for a long time now)

Answer (score 4):

That just happen to me and after some attempts I found the reason.

When I first opened the project in eclipse I found some errors related with the version of Java. I changed the JDK compliance to 1.6 (Project->Properties->Java Compiler) and all errors dissapear but all graphical layouts went blank.

I uncheked "**Enable project specific settings**" (Project->Properties->Java Compiler) and now all the graphical layouts are working.

Answer (score 4):

When everything fails, close eclipse and start it all over again, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem, it happened to me when i imported my project. after some time I came to reason just change the workspace of eclipse to folder, which contains your folder.
I changed workspace on opening eclipse, there can be some other way as well
hope this will solve it

Answer (score 0):

If it has never worked for you (or something went wrong upgrading your SDK, as in my case), you may need to install an extra package. For me the issue was fixed when I installed `Android Native Development Tools` under `NDK Plugins` (SDK version 20).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem since I switched the option Show previews in the palette. I switched to show only icons, everything is ok now.

Comment: Its not always the case. Sometimes Eclipse behaves abnormally or due to heavy lifting of xml layout, causes the Eclipse not to render the graphical view correctly. You just need to do two ways. The first is close your currnet `layout.xml` and re-open it. Or you can restart the Eclipse. This worked for me..